# I need to create word file by apex then user can open it from apex

Tags: apex

I need to create a word file by apex then a user should be able to open it from apex, edit and then save it. It should be saved as a BLOB or CLOB in the database and a user should be able to retrieve and print it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an Oracle 12c Database or any other Database with Java Support you should be able to create a word document with Java - that would be the easiest solution [(See here for an example in Java)](https://www.swtestacademy.com/generate-word-document-with-java/).

To be able to edit it just give an option for the user to download the File that was created by the Java inside the Database and then Upload it to the Server again. Apex has built in API's for [Downloading and uploading](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13363/up_dn_files.htm#HTMAD008) files to Apex.